# Concurrent users trying to insert and update in same SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where 50-70 users are trying to do API calls to insert records in SQL Server tables and also update the existing records at the same time.

SQL server version is as below

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467) - 14.0.3356.20 (X64)   Aug 20 2020 22:33:27   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: )
> (Hypervisor)

To avoid selects, AWS is doing READ REPLICA of audit tables to a new database.

However, `INSERT` + `UPDATE` on the same table (may be different records) are creating deadlocks.

How can this be handled in a seamless way ?

Generally this type of concurrent web application : how do they manage deadlocks? Should there by any queue mechanisms to set the order? If yes, how ?

Comment: The solution here will depend on the details of how the application works.

Comment: Yes.  You can generally avoid deadlocs.  Note you can _also_ retry over deadlocks, but it's generally better to make changes to your code to avoid them.  To troubleshoot deadlocks, post the deadlock XML in your question, along with the table and index DDL.  Sometimes you need to change an index, sometimes you need a lock hint or to change your transaction boundaries.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/analyze-prevent-deadlocks?view=azuresql&tabs=ring-buffer

Comment: I think that deadlocks are rare, as opposed to "hold locks" or "wait locks", and are usually a result of a design or implementation flaw in the calling program.  The most popular causes: holding a transaction open while waiting for a user and having two different parts of an application access resources in a transaction but in the opposit order.)